# Компоновщик не может разрешить переменную и функцию

Tags: c

С парой "reader"-файлов проблем нет.
*reader.h*

```
#ifndef READER_H
#define READER_H

struct text_driver { /* ... */ };
extern struct text_driver reader;
void getch(void);

#endif
```

*reader.c*

```
#include "reader.h"

struct text_driver reader;
void getch(void) {/* ... */ }
```

С данной же парой не всё так хорошо. Компоновщик не может разрешить **current_token**, хотя в прошлых файлах таким способом я объявил и определил **reader**
*scanner.h*

```
#ifndef SCANNER_H
#define SCANNER_H

struct token { /* ... */ };
extern struct token current_token;
void gettok(void);

#endif
```

*scanner.c*

```
#include "reader.h"
#include "scanner.h"

struct token current_token;
void gettok(void) { /* ... */ }
```

А здесь линкер не может разрешить использование **gettok**.
*main.c*

```
#include "reader.h"
#include "scanner.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // ...
    gettok();
    // ...
}
```

Почему линковщик не может разрешить эти символы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы компоновщик мог разрешить определения, сделанные в `reader.c` и `scanner.c`, эти файлы должны, условно выражаясь, "являться частью проекта". То есть результаты компиляции `reader.c` и `scanner.c` - объектные файлы `reader.o` и `scanner.o` - должны быть переданы на вход компоновщику. У вас, во-видимому, это не сделано.